# Why does my null model validate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Required]
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }

    public string Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

which I'm validating in my ASP.NET MVC API:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Foo foo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Valid
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid
    }
}
```

If I send a POST with no key/value pairs (making `myModel` null), my ModelState as marked is valid. Why is this? It correctly marks it as invalid if I provide just the `Bar2` key.

Comment: } is missing after Bar1 {get;set;

Comment: @Kuzgun Thank you - just an error in transcribing from my real-world code to an example.

Comment: Are `Foo` and `MyModel` supposed to be the same class?

Comment: Should be `public HttpResponseMessage Post(Foo myModel)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design. If your model is null, no validation is performed. If on the other hand your model is not null, but the `Bar1` property is null or an empty string you will get a validation error.

For example you will get a validation error with the following payload:

```
{ "Bar2": "Bazinga" }
```

or with this one:

```
{ "Bar1": null, "Bar2": "Bazinga" }
```

or with this one:

```
{ "Bar1": "", "Bar2": "Bazinga" }
```

Comment: @MrJones Why would it assume you are saving your model or that having a null model is not allowed?

Comment: By "no validation is performed" are you saying that ModelState.IsValid should return true?

Comment: Thanks Darin. What's the best way to output an appropriate error response?